# How can I loop through Access Field Names by index?

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access, recordset

I am trying to build an Access db of inspection data for mass manufactured plastic parts from a bunch of Excel sheets, which come from different sources.

I am doing this with two Access files: one as the front end/UI (Forms and Macros), and one as the back end (Tables containing the desired data).

My process:

1. Use front end Access Form to open the `msoFileDialogFilePicker` and select an Excel sheet of data to get read into my back end Access Table. The Table where the data is stored in the back end file depends on radio buttons selections in the front end file Form.
2. Macro reads data from Excel sheet, transposes data, and stores it in a new dumpSheet at the end of the original data file. Each row in this dumpSheet is effectively its own record in the corresponding back end Access table. Data gets read into back end Access Tables using `DAO.Database` and `DAO.Recordset`.
3. Repeat with new inspection data as it comes in every two weeks.

The inspection data comes from different sources, but it can be for the same plastic part. This combination of company + part dictates which fields are of interest to be read into the recordset. For example, all of these combinations would have different fields (each combination has its own table), but there is new inspection data for each combination every two weeks (hence the need for a db):

- Company X + Part A
- Company X + Part B
- Company Y + Part A
- Company Y + Part B

Here is a general look at how I'm setting this up in the Access front end Form Macro (where the fields listed in the `Do While` Loop are for one specific Company + Part combination:

```
Set excelTemp = New Excel.Application
excelTemp.Visible = True
excelTemp.DisplayAlerts = True
Set trExcelWB = excelTemp.Workbooks.Open("myExcelData.xlsx")  'Picked from msoDialogFilePicker

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = trExcelWB.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Dim dbDump As DAO.Database
Set dbDump = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("backend-database.accdb")

Dim dumpTable as String
dumpTable = "myTableForDataInBackEndDB"

Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Set tdf = dbDump.TableDefs(dumpTable)

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = dbDump.OpenRecordset(Name:=dumpTable)

With rst
    .AddNew
    Dim n as Integer
    n = 2
    
    Do While Len(ws.Cells(n,5).Value) > 0  '5th column of dumpSheet stores unique part IDs and governs end of my dataset on the dumpSheet
        .AddNew
                
        ![Date of Inspection] = ws.Cells(n, 2).Value
        ![Date of Production] = ws.Cells(n, 3).Value
        ![LOT] = ws.Cells(n, 4).Value
        ![Serial] = ws.Cells(n, 5).Value
        ![Part] = ws.Cells(n, 6).Value
               
        ![Depth] = ws.Cells(n, 7).Value
        ![Wall thickness] = ws.Cells(n, 8).Value

        .Update

        n = n + 1

    Loop
```

Which works in the case where I have:

*Date of Inspection*
*Date of Production*
*LOT*
*Serial*
*Part*
*Depth*
*Wall Thickness*

As my field names. These are my headers in only one case of many.

I would like something like this in my `Do While` Loop:

```
Do While Len(ws.Cells(n,5).Value) > 0

    Dim col as Integer
    For col = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        .AddNew
        ![dbDump.TableDefs(dumpTable).Fields(col - 1).Name] = ws.Cells(n, col).Value
    Next col

    .Update

    n = n + 1

Loop
```

I get an Error

> "Item not found in Collection".

I'm confused because `dbDump.TableDefs(dumpTable).Fields(col - 1).Name` on its own gives me the name of the field I want as a string, but I cannot figure out how to call it in the `dbDump` from this code.

I've looked and can't figure out how to loop through field names via index and not name.

Comment: `.Fields(dbDump.TableDefs(dumpTable).Fields(col - 1).Name)`

Comment: ...square brackets are for cases where the name is not a legal identifier (eg. if it has spaces) but they can't be used to evaluate pieces of VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you!! I had previously tried removing the square brackets and was getting the same problem while using `!dbDump.TableDefs(dumpTable).Fields(col - 1).Name`, much like I would if I was using a field name with no spaces.

Your comment made me realize though that my issue was actually the absence of the `.Fields` pointer, which has solved my problem. Thank you kindly!

Comment: But why are you retriving the "name" property of the field in question when you JUST said you don't want the name? You can't go Fields(5).Name = "some value", since that would be in theory changing the NAME of the database column!!! - So, use Fields(5).Value, or just Fields(5) since "value" is the default property. But why would you use fields(5).Name to get the name of the column when you don't care and you don't want to change the name of the column, but want to change the .value? And pull/use/reference the .fields collection from the recordset - not from the base table.